# Counting Sort program

Tags: java, sorting

I wrote this code for sorting the elements of an array using counting sort. The program compiles and runs but does not give the correct output. I expect the elements to be sorted in non-decreasing order. The output that I am getting is sorted in non-decreasing order but the values aren't the same that I had input. I have checked the code many times but I am not able to spot the error. Please help.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String aa[]) {

    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int t = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        int a [] = new int[t];
        int c [] = new int[t];
        int max = 0;

        if(t<=1000000) {

            for(int i = 0; i<t; i++) {
                int n = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
                if(n>=0 && n<=1000000) {
                    a[i] = n;
                    if(n>max) max = n;
                }
            }

            int b[] = new int[max+1];

            for(int i = 0; i<max+1; i++)
                b[i] = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i<t; i++)
                b[a[i]] += 1;

            for(int i = 1; i<max+1; i++)
                b[i] += b[i-1];

            for (int i = t-1; i>=0; i--) {
                c[b[a[i]]] = a[i];
                b[a[i]]--;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i<t; i++) 
                System.out.println(c[i]);

        }
        else 
            System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you expect? What does it really give you?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @JeroenIngelbrecht I expect the elements to be sorted in non-decreasing order. The output that I am getting is sorted in non-decreasing order but the values aren't the same that I had input.

Comment: This doesnt even remotely resemble the psudeocode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm

Comment: it certainly is an original way of sorting ;-)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know that i shouldn't be asking to spot the errors but I coludn't find the error after going through the code many times and that is why i put it here. The problem is somewhere in the second last for loop but I am not able to get it.

Comment: Can you give some inputs that you have tested and what the program printed out?

Comment: How about you give your variables some meaningful names? Also, the loop after `int b[] = new int[max+1];` is useless: you're setting all elements in `b` to zero, but *they are already zero*: the array constructor does that for you. This isn't C where you have to reset arrays yourself before using them. :-P

Comment: @Genzer input 4 6 3 2 8 output 0 2 3 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about place where you are wrong. Change:

```
for (int i = t-1; i>=0; i--) {
     c[b[a[i]]] = a[i];
     b[a[i]]--;
}
```

into:

```
for (int i = 0; i<t; ++i) {
     c[b[a[i]]-1] = a[i];
     --b[a[i]];
}
```

And it should work fine for your test data.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! I am glad that at least someone bothered to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right. Change the following lines (off by one error)

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    c[b[a[i]] - 1] = a[i];
    b[a[i]]--;
}
```

Comment: Thnaks! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this for counting sort:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Counting sort.
 */
public class CountingSort {

    static int[] countingSort(int[] arr) {
        int arrMax = Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt();
        int[] occurances = new int[arrMax + 1];
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(n -> {
            occurances[n]++;
        });
        int[] result = new int[arr.length];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < occurances.length; a++) {
            if (occurances[a] > 0) {
                for (int b = 1; b <= occurances[a]; b++) {
                    result[counter] = a;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                     new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("iofiles/cs.out")));
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            String[] arrItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrItems[i]);
                arr[i] = arrItem;
            }
            int[] result = countingSort(arr);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(result[i]));
                if (i != result.length - 1) {
                    bufferedWriter.write(" ");
                }
            }
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample input:

100
63 25 73 1 98 73 56 84 86 57 16 83 8 25 81 56 9 53 98 67 99 12 83 89 80 91 39 86 76 85 74 39 25 90 59 10 94 32 44 3 89 30 27 79 46 96 27 32 18 21 92 69 81 40 40 34 68 78 24 87 42 69 23 41 78 22 6 90 99 89 50 30 20 1 43 3 70 95 33 46 44 9 69 48 33 60 65 16 82 67 61 32 21 79 75 75 13 87 70 33

Sample output:

1 1 3 3 6 8 9 9 10 12 13 16 16 18 20 21 21 22 23 24 25 25 25 27 27 30 30 32 32 32 33 33 33 34 39 39 40 40 41 42 43 44 44 46 46 48 50 53 56 56 57 59 60 61 63 65 67 67 68 69 69 69 70 70 73 73 74 75 75 76 78 78 79 79 80 81 81 82 83 83 84 85 86 86 87 87 89 89 89 90 90 91 92 94 95 96 98 98 99 99

Specifically, this method is doing the counting sort:

```
static int[] countingSort(int[] arr) {
        int arrMax = Arrays.stream(arr).max().getAsInt();
        int[] occurances = new int[arrMax + 1];
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(n -> {
            occurances[n]++;
        });
        int[] result = new int[arr.length];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < occurances.length; a++) {
            if (occurances[a] > 0) {
                for (int b = 1; b <= occurances[a]; b++) {
                    result[counter] = a;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```